# Java/Android xml parsing

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse data from the google api:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/videos?q=kittens&client=ytapi-youtube-search&v=2&start-index=1

Like this

```
try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml.trim())));


} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            System.out.println("XML parse error: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
} catch (SAXException e) {
            System.out.println("Wrong XML file structure: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
} catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("I/O exeption: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
}
```

And keep getting a 'SAXException'.. what am I doing wrong ?

The precise error message is:I/System.out(19026): Wrong XML file structure: Unexpected token (position:TEXT null@1:104174 in java.io.StringReader@410c2448)

Comment: if you print out the xml, what does it look like? (are you sure it is getting all of it, etc?)

Comment: In eclipse, if I print it, it shows me only the start of it with an ending .. (please forgive me not knowing how to do some of these things, i am a beginner @CasualT

Comment: Why would someone down vote this ? I'm trying to be clear in the question, provide sample data, and explained precisely what I'm doing ?? If it's too simple of a question, then please help me with a simple answer.  I'm a beginner and could use the help. If I should ask the question differently, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have made this and it works for me :

```
public static void readGDATA(){

      DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder db = null;
      Document doc = null;

      try {

        db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = db.parse(new URL("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/videos?q=kittens&client=ytapi-youtube-search&v=2&start-index=1").openStream());
        System.out.println(doc.getElementsByTagName("name").getLength());



      } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 


}
```

Output in the console :

26